# Finding out the data type of a value in Presto

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I'm getting values from nested maps and it's hard to figure out what data type each value is. Is there a `typeof` function that can tell me the data type of each value?

Comment: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html maybe this could help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, there is the [`typeof`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#typeof) function:

```
presto> select typeof(1), typeof('a');
  _col0  |   _col1
---------+------------
 integer | varchar(1)
(1 row)
```